# ASP.NET MVC - Custom Cache Busting Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, bundling-and-minification

Supposedly, when a file included in a bundle is modified, the url key is supposed to be updated, forcing the client to clear its cache.

However, I have found this to be a very unreliable process - for some reason, the URL key is not always changed even when there are many changes to the underlying files.

So what I wanted to do was to use the assembly version in the query string so that whenever a release occurred, all clients would clear their cache so that they would be updated to the most recent version.  Here is what I have so far:

Custom transform to modify query variables:

```
public class VersionBusterTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse Response)
    {           
        string query = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", Global.Properties.Version.Major, Global.Properties.Version.Minor, Global.Properties.Version.Release, Global.Properties.Version.Build);
        Array.ForEach(Response.Files.ToArray(), x => x.IncludedVirtualPath = string.Concat(x.IncludedVirtualPath, "?v=", query));
    }
}
```

Registering the files:

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = (Global.Properties.Deployment.Environment != DeploymentEnvironment.Development);
 var StyleLibrary = new StyleBundle(ConfigBundles.Styles);
 StyleLibrary.Include("~/Content/Styles/Libraries/core-{version}.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
 StyleLibrary.Include("~/Content/Styles/Libraries/icomoon/style.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
 StyleLibrary.Include("~/Content/Styles/Site.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform());
 StyleLibrary.Transforms.Add(new VersionBusterTransform());
 BundleTable.Bundles.Add(StyleLibrary);

 var ScriptLibrary = new ScriptBundle(ConfigBundles.Scripts);
 ScriptLibrary.Include("~/Content/Scripts/Libraries/modernizr-{version}.js");
 ScriptLibrary.Include("~/Content/Scripts/Libraries/bootstrap-{version}.js");
 ScriptLibrary.Include("~/Content/Scripts/Framework/yeack.js");
 ScriptLibrary.Transforms.Add(new JsMinify());
 ScriptLibrary.Transforms.Add(new VersionBusterTransform());
 BundleTable.Bundles.Add(ScriptLibrary);
```

Method to get URL:

```
public static string Query(string Path)
{
    if (HttpRuntime.Cache[Path] == null)
    {
        var absolutePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Path);
            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(Path, string.Format("{0}?v={1}.{2}.{3}.{4}", Path, Global.Properties.Version.Major, Global.Properties.Version.Minor, Global.Properties.Version.Release, Global.Properties.Version.Build), new CacheDependency(absolutePath));
    }
    return HttpRuntime.Cache[Path] as string;
}
```

Header template:

```
@Styles.Render(ConfigBundles.Styles)
@Scripts.Render(ConfigBundles.Scripts)
```

Currently, when I open the site in the Development environment, the following references are printed in the header:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/Libraries/core-3.1.0.css?v=0.3.5.0" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Styles/Libraries/icomoon/style.css?v=0.3.5.0" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/Styles/Site.css?v=0.3.5.0" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/Content/Scripts/Libraries/modernizr-2.6.2.js?v=0.3.5.0"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/Libraries/bootstrap-3.0.0.js?v=0.3.5.0"></script>
<script src="/Content/Scripts/Framework/yeack.js?v=0.3.5.0"></script>
```

However, in Production, it is printing this:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/css?v=SmKL_qNLRzByCaBc0zE--HPqJmwlxxsS9p8GL7jtFsc1" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/Content/Scripts/js?v=YvUa47U8N_htaVmoq5u1VzHyRgEH3quFSUYpjRonpbM1"></script>
```

Why doesn't my bundling transform have any effect on what is printed in production?

Comment: Isn't your real problem *the URL key is not always changed even when there are many changes to the underlying files*. This shouldn't be happening. The key generated is a Hash of the underlying file. any change, no matter how small should update your hash. I've not seen this fail, so you should figure out what's causing your actual issue rather than re-invent the wheel. BTW the hash is only updated on App pool recycle as it's cached

Comment: `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = (Global.Properties.Deployment.Environment != DeploymentEnvironment.Development);` check this

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  Are you saying cache busting doesn't work in debug but does in production?  If so, that's by design (sort of).  Or are you saying that the hash does not change in production even when the files are updated?  If so, are you sure they are actually updated?  And not just the non-minified versions?